# Using Core Data with Images or buttons (or anything besides a tableView)

Tags: ios, core-data, uibutton, uiimage

I'm trying to build an application that uses something like the following data model. I can do this fine in a tableView but I would like to be more creative. For Example, Inside a navigation controller, I want to have a view that has 10 images (or buttons with an image as a background).

(three entities)

entity 1: House

- attribute: houseName
- relationship:person

entity 2:Person

- attribute: personName
- relationship:house
- relationship:children

entity 3:Children

- attribute:name
- attribute:birthPlace
- relationship: adult

relationships are one to many down from
attributes are all strings

person<---->>house, children<--->>adult

In the first view there are images and each image is assigned to entity House (houseName 1, houseName 2, etc.). When you select a house it pushes the next view with 5 images (that is linked to the Person Entity (personName 1, personName2, etc). When you select the PersonName it will push the next view populated with the Children Entity.

I've read quite a bit of info on core data and I'm comfortable doing this:

```
NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = [[managedObject valueForKey@"houseName"] description];
```

but very unsure where I should even start with using and image or button to do this

I was thinking of something like this:

```
-(id)initWithHouseViewController:(HouseViewController*)aHouseViewController house:(NSManagedObject *)aHouse{
if blah blah
self.houseViewController = aHouseViewController;
self.house = aHouse
  }return self;
}
```

// for a selector

```
 -(void) showPersonView{
PersonViewController *pvc = [[PersonViewController alloc] initWithHouseViewController:self house:house];
```

in the viewDidLoad

```
{
if (house != nil) {
UIImageView *house1 = [[ UIImageView alloc.. blah blah
some kind of..  action:@selector(showPersonView)
((for each houseName in house) instead of house1, house2,)
...
}
```

Any suggestions with the viewDidLoad where I wouldn't need to hard code in each image (or button) would be great to make this more portable. Also, I'm not rooted to doing it this way if there are suggestions as to a nicer/more creative way to do this.

Sorry if this is a bit messy. It's messy in my mind as well.

Thanks for taking your time to read this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use FetchResultController in this case.

Instead You can try This:

Create a view controller that will show all the houses as buttons, you can dynamically create the buttons according to the "Houses" count.
It will look something like this:

```
 NSArray * allHouses = [Houses allObjects];
 //you can sort them if you need

[allHouses enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {


    //create the buttons as custom and you can add any image to the button
    UIButton *button....
    button
   //store the house index as the button tag, so you can get it later
    button.tag = idx;
  //add a selector to the button
   [button addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(getPersons:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
}];
```

Create a new PersonViewController that will hold the persons. the view controller should get the house as the parameter and not the person. After it gets the house you will get the persons with the relationShip.

Now add this method to get the :

```
  -(void)getPersons(UIButton*)sender{
        NSInteger *tag = sender.tag;
         House * house = (House*)[allHouses objectAtIndex:tag];

        PersonViewController *pvc = [[PersonViewController alloc] init];
          pvc.house = house;
         [self.navigationController pushViewController.....];
```

}

Inside the person view controller you can get all the persons or with fetch request or simply with :

```
         NSArray *allPersons = [house.person all objects];
```

Again create the persons buttons  the same as you did with the first view controller.

Reapit the same procedure with the Children view controller.

GoodLuck

Shani

Comment: Thanks Shani, 
I'm not sure how to get from aHouse to a count of Houses outside of a table view. I'm sure I'm just missing something simple but the frustration bug has hit.

Comment: Can you explain your question again? I am not sure I got it right.

Comment: So you're saying I should subclass NSManagedObject #import for each NSMO then NSArray *allHouses = [Houses allObjects] right?

Comment: I'd also be happy with a non-dynamic way of doing this as I'm not able to do it this way

Comment: Hi, can you explain what id that you can not understand?

Comment: My problem is with the bit before you have NSArray *allHouses = [Houses AllObjects]. I'm unsure how to get my code ready for that without a fetched results controller.

Comment: Did you subclassed your entities from core data

Comment: first thanks for trying to help me - I used the 'Create Managed Object Subclass' option while in the model. In the header file of the view controller I have Class House and House *house; and property (strong, nonatomic) House *House; In the implementation: synthesize house; but that is as far as I've gotten. I've tried setting up a managed object context but that hasn't worked.

Comment: It is hard to see the problem. if you want send me your project to shannoga AT me DOT com. And I will look at it.

Comment: guess you're stumped. I'll just try to reform my idea about how to put this together and see if someone esle can figure it out